# tkz euclide How to give arrowheads on both sides to axes?

Tags: arrows, plot, tkz-euclide

I'm using tkz-base and trying to plot inequation on x axis. I wanted to show arrowheads on both sides but when drawing X axis I get arrowhead only on right side. How do I get on both sides?

I tried to search the docs but couldn't understand. I tried to use the usual `<->` option, but it didn't work.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{tkz-base,tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \tkzInit[xmin=-3, xmax=9]
            \tkzDrawX[left space=0.5,label={}]
            \tkzDrawSegment[latex-latex,color=black]({-3.5,0},{9.5,0}) % workaround to get arrow at left side
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

PS: I have achieved it by using a workaround i.e. by drawing a segment on the axis which has arrows on both sides. But I would prefer, if there is a solution which allows us to given option to the `\tkzAxeX` or `\tkzDrawX`.

Comment: I have added part of the code from whole document which is large.

Comment: Okay, I'll update it. I'm a little new to this. Thanks for letting me know. :)

Comment: I have updated the code which is compilable and can be copied immediately for checking.

Comment: Great. Upvoted your question. Now you only have to wait for answers :))

Comment: Oh, thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `xaxe style` to customize x axis, the original definition of this style is

```
\tikzset{xaxe style/.style ={>=latex,->}}
```

You can redefine it like this

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{tkz-base,tkz-euclide}

\tikzset{xaxe style/.style ={>=latex,<->}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \tkzInit[xmin=-3, xmax=9]
            \tkzDrawX[left space=0.5,label={}]
         \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This has been very helpful to me.

Comment: One more thing, how can I see the original definitions ?

Comment: Page 92 of tkz-base manual http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tkz/tkz-base/doc/tkz-base-screen.pdf

Comment: Ironically, the link to the pdf you shared, show only 91 pages when I opened in a new tab of my chrome browser.

Comment: Page 82, sorry.

Comment: Oh, Thank you very much. :)