# I don't want labels (numbers) on both x-axis and y-axis

Tags: tkz-euclide

Actually i am trying to produce two axes in tkz-Euclid in which i don't want to show numbers on both axis. i just want simple dots instead of numbers. Is it possible?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{article}

\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \tkzInit[xmax=5,ymax=5,xmin=-5,ymin=-5]
   \tkzAxeXY
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to remove the labels but keep the small lines you can use `\tktDrawXY` instead of `\tkzAxeXY`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \tkzInit[xmax=5,ymax=5,xmin=-5,ymin=-5]
   \tkzDrawXY
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

---

In the documentation of `tkz-euclid` and `tkz-base` I was not able to find an easy solution on how to replace the ticks with small circles. You could use a for loop as shown in the following example. I have also used `\tkzSetUpAxis` to remove the original ticks. With `\tikzset{xaxe style/.style ={>=latex,-}}` I have removed the arrow head from the x axis (inspired from here: [tkz euclide How to give arrowheads on both sides to axes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/483306/134144))

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\tikzset{xaxe style/.style ={>=latex,-}}
\tikzset{yaxe style/.style ={>=latex,-}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \tkzInit[xmax=5,ymax=5,xmin=-5,ymin=-5]
   \tkzSetUpAxis[ticka=0pt, tickb=0pt]
   \tkzDrawXY

    \foreach \x in {-5,...,5}
     \draw [fill] (\x,0) circle [radius=1pt];
    \foreach \y in {-5,...,5}  
      \draw [fill] (0,\y) circle [radius=1pt];

   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @ leandriis right but how these small lines replaced by small dots and secondly i don't arrow style on both ends of axes

Comment: @Sandy: I have updated my answer.

Comment: Great i came to know few interesting things. Should i ask a question?

Comment: labels x on right side, x' on left side

Comment: Regarding the requested style with arrow heads on both ends of the axis: You could use `\tikzset{xaxe style/.style ={>=latex,<->}}` as shown here: [tkz euclide How to give arrowheads on both sides to axes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/483306/134144). Regarding the second part of your comment: I unfortunately don't seem to understand the requirements. Could you please show a sketch of the desired result?

Comment: In your updated output we find x label on the right side. In similar manner i wish to write x ' on the left side of axis, exactly in opposite side

Comment: There is apparently no built in function in `tkz-euclide` to include two lables to a single axis. But you can always use a node to add text where you want to. For example something like `\node at (-5.25,-5pt) {$x'$};`.